# Chrome shows scrolls on overflow:visible;

Tags: jquery, css

After click element get class

```
wrapperInner.addClass('wrapper_inner_extended');
```

so it has `class='wrapper_inner wrapper_inner_extended'`

here is those 2 classes definition

```
div.wrapper_inner {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper_inner_extended {
    background:#000000;
    color:#ffffff!important;
    z-index:9000!important;
    height:auto!important;
    overflow:visible!important  ;
}
```

In FF it works just fine but in Chrome I see scrolls instead. Check this url http://copy.barchick.com/calendar/ , click on red '...' on 1 Novemeber to replicate this issue. Please help me to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the wrapping `<td>` is what has the scrollbars. They disappeared when I put `overflow:visible` on that `<td>`.

Tables are still handled pretty differently between browsers.